# Transformation of Polynomial Sum through Input Change of Variable

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, complex-numbers

I have a polynomial, I'll call $P(x)$.  This polynomial has rational coefficients and consider inputs, $z$ over the Complex numbers, such that $|z|<3$.  Now also suppose that I have

$$P\left(z+\frac{2}{3}\right)+w_3^2P\left(z+\frac{w_3+1}{3}\right)+w_3P\left(z+\frac{w_3^2+1}{3}\right)=z^n$$

Here $w_3$ is the third root of unity.  I am hoping to see if there is a transformation, $z=ax+b$, where $x$ is also complex, so that

$$w_3P\left(x+\frac{2}{3}\right)+P\left(x+\frac{w_3+1}{3}\right)+w_3^2P\left(x+\frac{w_3^2+1}{3}\right)=(ax+b)^n$$

Simply attempting to suppose there is a $y$ such that

$$z+y+\frac{2}{3}=z+\frac{w_3+1}{3}$$ shows that $y=\frac{w_3-1}{3}$
but doing this for the next polynomial term shows this does not work since
$$z+y+\frac{w_3+1}{3}=z+\frac{w_3^2+1}{3}$$
gives $y=\frac{w_3^2-w_3}{3}$.

I feel close, but not exactly what I need.  Is there something I should be doing?  Should I not assume linear transformation and perhaps something different?

EDIT:  I changed the condition on |z| to more accurately reflect what I'm looking for.

Comment: is the first relation valid for all $z$ or for one particular $z$ ?

Comment: Valid for all $z$, @mercio, thanks.

Comment: then it's also valid for $x$ so you have no chance of achieving what you want.

Comment: if the first relations is valid for enough complex numbers (more than $n$ and more than the degree of $P$) then it's automatically true for all complex numbers.

Comment: Okay, I understand that, but how do I find a particular value for $y$ above?